# Initialise const member variables in class using values from file input

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

I want to define a `const` variable which is part of a class like:

```
// camera.h
class Camera{
public:
    Camera(std::string file);
    ~Camera() {}
    const size_t FRAME_HEIGHT;
    const size_t FRAME_WIDTH;
private:
    std::string file;
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    Read();
};
```

_____________________________________

```
// camera.cpp
Camera::Camera(std::string file) : file("settings.yml") {
    //...
    read();
    cap.open(0);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
}

void Camera::read(){
    // read something
}
```

However this does not work using an initialisation list because I first have to read this data from a settings file.

After calling `read()` I set my `const` variables `FRAME_HEIGHT` and `FRAME_WIDTH`.

Is it possible to leave them `const` and if yes how/where should I do that?

Comment: just check is const references serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you use an intermediate class, like this:

```
class Camera {
    struct Reader {
        int value;

        Reader(bool x) {
            // Do whatever you like
            value = x ? 42 : 0xDEAD;
        }
    };
    Camera(Reader&& r) : value(::std::move(r.value)) { }

public:
    int const value;

    template<typename... V>
    Camera(V... args)
    : Camera(Reader(std::forward<V>(args)...))
    { }
};
```

This effectively adds another stage to the initialization, but still keeps encapsulation (`Reader` and the corresponding constructor are private to `Camera`!). The performance impact should be negligible (forward and move operations are usually cheap), unless you initialize millions of these objects in some tight inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to initialize a settings object from a file, and take needed values from it:

```
class Camera
{
    // note this section is moved to the beginning,
    // so file and settings are initialized before FRAME_HEIGHT and FRAME_WIDTH
private:
    std::string file;
    Settings settings;
public:
    Camera(std::string file)
        : file(file)
        , settings(file)
        , FRAME_HEIGHT(settings.getFrameHeight())
        , FRAME_WIDTH(settings.getFrameWidth())
    {
    }

    ~Camera() {}
    const size_t FRAME_HEIGHT;
    const size_t FRAME_WIDTH;
};
```

Also it could make sense to rewrite `Camera` constructor after that as

```
    Camera(const Settings& settings)
        : FRAME_HEIGHT(settings.getFrameHeight())
        , FRAME_WIDTH(settings.getFrameWidth())
    {
    }
```

-- this way you can take settings from anywhere, not only from a file.